# would rather + past perfect + a point in the future

Tags: construction

Can the past perfect be used to indicate a future action?

I would rather you **had finished** trimming the lawn by the time we come back.

Comment: Where's the future action? There's a present request, but no idea what the future will be.

Comment: This is the future action "by the time we come back."

Comment: That's just a point in time. A request in the present was made, but we have no idea whether the action (trimming the lawn) will actually happen in the future. So, "a point in the future", yes. "A future action", it's unknown.

Comment: It's quibbling. It's a hypothetical future action. Plus it's absolutely out of the scope of the question how precisely it should be named or called.